# Which JavaME enabled phones has JSR-253 (if any)?

Tags: java-me, midp, midp-2.0

I need to create a cellphone app that catches the phone-numbers of incoming calls. I don't need to actually do anything with the call itself. Just catch the phone-number.
I looked briefly at PushRegistry first, and experimented with a tel:// protocol (since that's what's used to make a call using platformRequest). But it wouldn't install on my Sony Ericsson Aino, so I guess it can't be done that way.

I then learned that it seemingly can be done with JSR-253. But I'm having trouble finding any phones that supports JSR-253.

PhoneArena.com says Sony Ericsson Hazel supports JSR-253:
http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Sony-Ericsson-Hazel_id4276/fullspecs

But Sony Ericsson's own white paper for Hazel doesn't mention JSR-253:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/whitepapers/sony-ericsson-hazel-white-paper/

I'm thinking maybe there was a firmware update that included JSR-253? I don't have a Sony Ericsson Hazel to test on, and I don't feel like getting one if it won't work.

Anyway, the question is: How can I find a list of phones that supports JSR-253?

Thanks

Comment: you can try contacting the actual people involved in the JSR (using http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=253) directly but, considering how JavaME development has evolved inside the main handset manufacturers since the specification was finalized, I would bet good money that you will simply not be able to do what you want on any existing phone.

Comment: I suspect you're right. Thanks for the suggestion. I've written them an e-mail now.

Comment: No reply. So, in conclusion, this is not possible to do with JavaME, as there apparently exists no devices with JSR-253. At least, if such a device exists, then it is a well-kept secret.
I guess I'll have to "settle" for Android then.
Thanks to those who upvoted the question and to those who tried to help.